# Updating linux-headers-aws breaks ixgbevf

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel

When I attempt to update `linux-headers-aws` on my instance, it becomes unconnectable after restart. Diffing the AWS system log from the console, I found:

> ixgbevf: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

Do I need to reinstall ixgbevf? Should I avoid updating in this manner?

Pre-update:

`uname -a`

> Linux master 4.4.0-1022-aws #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 27 11:27:55 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`modinfo ixgbevf`

> modinfo ixgbevf filename:
>   /lib/modules/4.4.0-1022-aws/updates/dkms/ixgbevf.ko version:
>   3.1.2 license:        GPL description:    Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Virtual Function Network Driver author:         Intel Corporation,
>    srcversion:     BA90EAFD4DC7D0F8F47AB8D alias: 
>   pci:v00008086d000015A8sv*sd*bc*sc*i* alias:
>   pci:v00008086d00001565sv*sd*bc*sc*i* alias:
>   pci:v00008086d00001515sv*sd*bc*sc*i* alias:
>   pci:v00008086d000010EDsv*sd*bc*sc*i* depends: vermagic:
>   4.4.0-1022-aws SMP mod_unload modversions parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Maximum interrupts per second, per vector,
>   (956-488281, 0=off, 1=dynamic), default 1 (array of int)

`ethtool -i ens3`

> driver: ixgbevf version: 3.1.2 firmware-version: N/A
>   expansion-rom-version: bus-info: 0000:00:03.0 supports-statistics: yes
>   supports-test: yes supports-eeprom-access: no supports-register-dump:
>   yes supports-priv-flags: no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/andrewrech/4bd15a195489b864bdf46ee43df3eb3c)

First I created a backup AMI and unheld these packages:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-aws
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-headers-aws
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-image-aws
sudo apt-mark unhold lxd
sudo apt-mark unhold lxd-client
```

Then updated:

`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-aws linux-image-aws`

This ran successfully:

```
Setting up linux-headers-aws (4.4.0.1026.29) ...
Setting up linux-aws (4.4.0.1026.29) ...
```

Several attempts to reboot at this point rendered my AMI unconnectable with the error message in the system log documented in my question. So I re-downloaded ixgbevf according to the AWS documentation and re-installed, **commenting out the version check line to allow compilation (#if UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI > 255)**. This required that I first uninstall the existing ixgbevf-3.1.2 module:

```
sudo dkms remove ixgbevf/3.1.2 --all
sudo dkms add -m ixgbevf -v 3.1.2
sudo dkms build -m ixgbevf -v 3.1.2
sudo dkms install -m ixgbevf -v 3.1.2 --all
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
sudo reboot
```

And I was then able to successfully connect.